# Example Jenkins file for a Visual Studio build?

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, svn, jenkins-plugins

Working on automating our build process using Jenkins and I'm about to pull my hair out, which I don't have much of. :)

Set up a Jenkins server, and am setting up a pipeline. Not 100% sure if we should go scripted or declaritive, but in either case, I'm having a huge issue finding any concrete examples, documentation or books.

Our use case is seemingly extremely simple.

1. Pull code from Subversion
2. Build solution using Visual Studio
3. Push executable to file server
4. Run powershell script on a server to deploy

I'd be happy to be able to figure out how to do just 1 and 2 for starters.

I've got the VS Build and Subversion plugins. Running Jenkins ver. 2.190.3

Answer (score -1):

This can be done with jenkins declarative pipelines.
There are nice youtube tutorial for such simple cases.

Comment: I've looked for tutorials for that use case, but have not found anything. The documentation for Jenkins declarative does not seem very good. Can you provide a link to a good tutorial video? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=79HfmjeOTEI <- This one really helps you to start from scratch.